# Loading a JSON in python

Tags: python, json

I've got a problem loading a JSON in python. I'm working with python 2.7 and I've got a JSON file that I would like to load. I did:

```
movies = json.load(open(FBO_REF_FILE, 'r'))
```

But when I display it I got a dict full of:

```
{u'id_yeyecine': 42753, u'budget_dollars': u'85', u'classification': u'Tous publics', u'pays': u'US', u'budget_euros': u'0', u'dpw_entrees_fr': 132326, u'realisateurs': u'Brad Peyton, Kevin Lima', u'is_art_et_essai': u'NON', u'distributeur_video': u'Warner hv', u'genre_gfk_1': u'ENFANT', u'genre_gfk_2': u'FILM FAMILLE', u'genre_gfk_3': u'FILM FAMILLE', u'is_3D': u'OUI', u'fid': 16429, u'cum_entrees_pp': 58076, u'titre': u'COMME CHIENS ET CHATS LA REVANCHE DE KITTY GALORE', u'psp_entrees': 963, u'cum_entrees_fr': 348225, u'dps_copies_fr': 453, u'dpj_entrees_pp': 7436, u'visa': 127021, u'dps_entrees_fr': 178908, u'genre': u'Com\xe9die', u'distributeur': u'WARNER BROS.', u'editeur_video': u'Warner bros', u'psp_copies': 15, u'dpw_entrees_pp': 26195, u'id_imdb': None, u'date_sortie_video': u'2010-12-06', u'dps_copies_pp': 39, u'date_sortie': u'2010-08-04', u'dps_entrees_pp': 32913, u'dpj_entrees_fr': 40369, u'ecrivains': u'', u'acteurs': u"Chris O'donnell, Jack McBrayer", u'is_premier_film': u'NON'}
```

I tried using ast but I got the following error: string malformed. The error I get when using last is the following:

```
    153     if cursor is None:
    154         movies = json.load(open(FBO_REF_FILE, 'r'))
--> 155         movies = ast.literal_eval(movies)
    156         for movie in movies:
    157             if movies[movie]['id_allocine'] == allocine_id:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.pyc in literal_eval(node_or_string)
     78                 return left - right
     79         raise ValueError('malformed string')
---> 80     return _convert(node_or_string)
     81 
     82 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.pyc in _convert(node)
     77             else:
     78                 return left - right
---> 79         raise ValueError('malformed string')
     80     return _convert(node_or_string)
     81 

ValueError: malformed string
```

Comment: What do you do to "display" `movies`? This looks fine to me: The JSON is parsed into a dict as expected.

Comment: Could you show us the content of the file??? Maybe you are getting the correct result

Comment: @LutzHorn I'm using print to display it

Comment: When exactly is the error happening? Can you provide the complete traceback and the calling code?

Comment: @juankysmith The file is not written with unicode

Comment: I dont't think there is anything wrong.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `json.load` you parse a json file into python's datatypes. In your case this is a dict.

With `open` you load a file.

If you don't want to parse the json file just do the following

```
content = None
with open(FBO_REF_FILE, 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
print content  # content is a string contaning the content of the file
```

If you want to parse the json file into python's datatypes do the following:

```
content = None
with open(FBO_REF_FILE, 'r') as f:
    content = json.loads(f.read())
print content  # content is a dict containing the parsed json data
print content['id_yeyecine']
print content['budget_dollars']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pretty print your dictionary:

```
json.dumps(movies, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Or use pprint: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html

Answer (score 2):

To read from `movies`, use regular dict methods:

```
id_yeyecine = movies["id_yeyecine"]
```

Now `id_yeyecine` is `42753`.